# Structure of data models in Angular by references. A different logic

Tags: angular, model

In my angular project I need 3 features for my models:

a) The models have a relation with other models in a large hierarchy, and I want to access the data relation by reading variables inside the model. Example: model A has a relation with model B, model B has a relation with model C, model C has a relation with model D, ... My goal here is be able to read the relation data like this:

```js
<div *ngFor="let elementA of modelA_list">
    <div *ngFor="let elementB of elementA.modelB_list">
        <div *ngFor="let elementC of elementB.modelC_list">
            {{elementC.something}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

b) The relation between models is, some times, bidireccional. For example: model A has a relation with model B, and model B has a relation with model A. This produces circular dependency error caused by the imports.

c) I want an unique object with the same id for each model type. This is because if an element change I want an update of the info in other places in application that are showing info about this element. For example:

```js
// first fragment
<div *ngFor="let elementA of modelA_list">
    <div *ngFor="let elementB of elementA.modelB_list">     
        <input [(ngModel)]="elementB.name"></div>   
    </div>
</div>

// second fragment
<div *ngFor="let elementC of modelC_list">
    <div *ngFor="let elementB of elementC.modelB_list">     
        {{elementB.name}}       
    </div>
</div>
```

In this code {{elementB.name}} is showing in two parts of the app, if the name of elementB changes in the input of the first fragmente, I want this info updates in the second fragment.

Thinking about this I had an idea. This idea is to build a system based on models that are interfaces. This models have empty variables of type `any[]` that will storages references to other model objects, based on relation data. This structure doesn´t cause circular dependecy error. To have a unique elenement with the same id for each model type there is a service who storages all the unique elements of a model type for each model type in the app. Finally a core service can return a list of objects of a model type and the relations with other models inside, builded in real time.

[image: Diagram Angular DataModel]

If you see the diagram, in "Component 1" you can get a list of elements (references) of model type modelA and a relation data with modelB and modelC like this:

```
+--ModelA[0]
   |
   +--id: 1
   |
   +--name: example 1a
   |
   +--models_b:
   |  |
   |  +--ModelB[0]
   |  |  |
   |  |  +--id: 1
   |  |  |
   |  |  +--name: example 1b
   |  |
   |  +--ModelB[1]
   |     |
   |     +--id: 2
   |     |
   |     +--name: example 2b
   |     |
   |     +--models_c
   |        |
   |        +--ModelC[0]
   |           |
   |           +--id: 1
   |           |
   |           +--name: example 1c
   |   
   +--models_c:
      |
      +--ModelC[0]
         |
         +--id: 1
         |
         +--name: example 1c
```

I´ve made a code to test this system: **[Codesandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-cphgf?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)**

At this point my questions are:

1) ¿Is right this system to manage models?

2) ¿Already exists something similar to this system?

3) If this system is not right ¿Which other logic can I do to solve this problem?

Sorry for my english and thanks for your help and time.

Comment: You should check [NgRx](https://ngrx.io/)

Comment: @Eldar thanks you. I think this is just I want. Im reading about NgRx, but I´m not sure if I can do biderectional realtions: model A contains elements of model B, and model B contains elements of model A. Do you know if it is possible?

Comment: There is a good [article](https://medium.com/visual-development/how-to-fix-nasty-circular-dependency-issues-once-and-for-all-in-javascript-typescript-a04c987cf0de) about circular references and how to fix them.